# Windows Batch File Environment Variable order dependancy

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I've got a simple batch file that is trying to create some folders before an application launches.
But I've hit a odd problem that I don't understand why its occurring.

The batch file takes 1 single parameter (a simple one word string), so I was originally had:

```
mkdir D:\Data\App\%username%\%1%
```

Which would create `D:\Data\App\User111\Bob` correctly for the user `User111` and the parameter `bob`.
But we wanted to swap the order to:

```
mkdir D:\Data\App\%1%\%username%
```

And that fails, it creates `D:\Data\App\Bobusername` :(

It's something to do with %1% but no idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use your first direct argument in creating the folder, eliminating the creation of unnecessary variables:

```py
mkdir "D:\Data\App\%~1\%username%"
```

Direct use your **`%1`**: 1st argument == **`%1`**

Or, without/removing double quotes **`""`** == **`%~1`**

- About: ***Which works, but no idea why,...***

  [image]

The interpreter is using its **`%1`** argument and also ignoring its second **`%`** in your command **`set %db%=%1%`**

```py
your batch/cmd command: set %db%=%1%
interpreter understand: set %db%=%1%
real command execution: set %db%=%1
```

**Obs.:** The original command/code `mkdir D:\Data\App\%1%\%username%` result explained:

[image]

The interpreter is using its **`%1`** argument

The interpreter is ignoring non-existing variable **`%\%`**

The interpreter is using ***`username`*** as a string only

The interpreter is ignoring the last **`%`** in command

```py
 your batch/cmd command: mkdir D:\Data\App\%1%\%username%
 interpreter understand: mkdir D:\Data\App\%1%\%username%
 real command execution: mkdir D:\Data\App\%1username
it's the same as typing: mkdir D:\Data\App\Bobusername
```

Comment: thank you, i'd inherited the batch file and didn't realise that `%1%` wasn't correct, so kept using it throughout.  In the other uses that erroneous `%` must have been harmless.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by assigning `%1%` to a different variable first, then using it.
So

```
set %db%=%1%
mkdir D:\Data\App\%db%\%username%
```

Which works, but no idea why, or if there was another solution.

Comment: Why are you using `%1%`  and not `%1`   ?

Comment: inherited the batch file, didn't realize that wasn't the right syntax.

Comment: You can read and study batch file syntax, so you understand how they work. There are many web sites. This is a good one. [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/)